# What's the HTML5 valid way of creating a border within a dropdown menu (unordered list)?

Tags: css, html, navigation

[www.amyyatsuk.com](http://amyyatsuk.com)

I ran the code through the validator and it didn't like my method of incorporating a div within the un-ordered list.  I'm trying to get an interior border on the drop down navigation menu.

What's the valid markup that would achieve this same effect?

HTML:

```
<div id="linksLeft">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li id="about"><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li id="portfolio"><a href="editorial.html">portfolio</a>
        <ul class="subMenu" id="subNav"> **<div id="subnavborder">**
            <li><a href="editorial.html">editorial</a></li>
            <li><a href="advertising.html">advertising</a></li>
            <li><a href="packaging.html">packaging</a></li>
            <li><a href="photography.html">photography</a></li> **</div>**
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#subnavborder {
    margin:10px;
    border: 6px solid white;
    border-radius:6px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `:after` pseudo selector, like so:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfq7g/)

```
.subMenu:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border: 6px solid white;
    border-radius:6px;
    position: relative;
    width: figure it out;
    height: figure it out;
    left: figure it out;
    top: figure it out;
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution. You should at least be using `position: absolute;` and `left`, `right`, etc values

Comment: @Bojangles Don't hate, it works great, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/vfq7g/ Why should I use `position: absolute;`?

Comment: The only thing I hate is that expression. What happens when the content has a different width or height? You should use position absolute because it allows the "outer border thingy" to resize dynamically with the box content

Answer (score 1):

**Two alternatives**

**Using regular borders  [regular fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/8qKLp/).** 
and
**Using internal borders [internal fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/Lz42a/)**

**Regular borders**
You can achive your border styling the UL element with this class

```
.subnavborder {
    margin:10px;
    border: 6px solid black;
    border-radius:6px;
}
```

Unless for other reason , you dont need the div
Markup as follows

```
<div id="linksLeft">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li id="about"><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li id="portfolio"><a href="editorial.html">portfolio</a>
        <ul class="subMenu subnavborder" id="subNav"> 
            <li><a href="editorial.html">editorial</a></li>
            <li><a href="advertising.html">advertising</a></li>
            <li><a href="packaging.html">packaging</a></li>
            <li><a href="photography.html">photography</a></li> 
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

See it in this  [regular fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/8qKLp/).
I changed the border color in order to show it
Then adjust exceeding classes at will.

**Alternative for internal border**

If you want to keep the radius, you will need to use pseudo element selectors as in this example

I am using the same markup as before.
The black border is there just to appreciate the inner border
The position relative is needed because we will position the pseudo element refering this one

```
 .subnavborder {
       position:relative;

        border:1px solid black;
    }
```

As the inner border could conflict with the list decorations we apply some margin (at your will)

```
    .subnavborder li{
       margin:10px;
    }
```

Now the pseudo element

```
.subnavborder:after {
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
    border-radius:6px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    right: 3px;
}
```

Get it?. We are adding a ghost element . Modify the deep in pixels, color , etc
See it working at this [internal fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/Lz42a/)

**No need of radius??**
If you dont want to use pseudo-elements there is a solution using the property **outline** (but not with radius...)
If you want it, ask for it and I include it here.

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants. They want an "inner" border. You've just given the `<ul>` a normal border

Comment: @Bojangles, You are right. I misss the interior esp. I extend ASAP  my answer covering that matter

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking HTML5, you're also talking CSS3 which means `box-shadow` is commonly supported.

`box-shadow` supports an offset, which will allow you to appear to continue the background beyond the border.

Give this a go:

```
ul.subMenu {
    background-color: #93b9bb;
    border: 5px solid #fff

    /* Your other styles here */

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px #93b9bb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px #93b9bb;
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px #93b9bb;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px #93b9bb;
}
```

Take a look [at the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xGaUc/).

This doesn't use a `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element hack which leaves you with cleaner CSS, as well as the fact the box shadow is more easily controlled (no `position: absolute` and `left` `right`, etc values). The fourth pixel value in the above `box-shadow` property defines the shadow offset. The `0px` before it specifies a 0px blur i.e. a completely sharp shadow.

Comment: The OP wanted an "HTML5" solution, which generally means CSS3, and not caring about older browsers. I used box shadow because its the cleanest method.